# React Navigation navigate to a normal stackNavigator without BottomTabNavigator

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to navigate to a stackNavigator without using bottom tabs..

As you can see in the next image I have a header button to navigate to my profile stack..I want to be able to navigate without pressing any button from my bottom tab navigator..

[image]

So I nested two navigators one with the tabs buttons and the other a simple stack for the profile screens, the problem is that whenever I go to the profile stack I lost my bottom tab navigation as you can see the in the next image in the red box

[image]

So is there any way on how to merge both navigators so the bottom tab navigator always appears visible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add the profile link to bottom navigation also. but make the link hidden in bottom navigation so it will work.

If you provide the code i am also help.

Comment: this worked perfectly! I used this link https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5230 to implement your solution.